# How to check if cursor returns any records in oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-cursor

I have a following stored procedure in which I have used a cursor. Depending on whether the cursor return any records or not I need to do some processing.

But I am not sure how to check if the cursor return any records.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_EMPLOYEE_LOOKUP_BY_EMP_ID
(
      IN_USER_ID IN NUMBER, 
      IN_EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER,
      IN_HC_AS_ON_DATE VARCHAR2,
      emp_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
IS 

 CURSOR employees IS 
    SELECT  * FROM EMPLOYEE e; 

BEGIN    

if(record exist ) then 

 FOR employee IN employees
  LOOP  

        // do something  

  END LOOP; 
else if employees is empty then 
     // do something else 

END;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not possible to check if the cursor returns records without opening it.
(see [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:96612348060#6441370332689))
So you can either have some fast query just to see if there are records (using count for example),

Or, you can do it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_EMPLOYEE_LOOKUP_BY_EMP_ID
(
      IN_USER_ID IN NUMBER, 
      IN_EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER,
      IN_HC_AS_ON_DATE VARCHAR2,
      emp_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
IS 

 is_found_rec boolean := false;    

 CURSOR employees IS 
    SELECT  * FROM EMPLOYEE e; 

BEGIN    

 FOR employee IN employees
  LOOP  

    is_found_rec := true;

        // do something  

  END LOOP; 

 if not is_found_rec then 
     // do something else 
 end if;

END;
```

Answer (score 12):

I think that it possible only with `FETCH`. Try to use

```
if myCursor%found then
// some body
end if;
```

But if somebody know another way so correct me.

Comment: Yes, without `FETCH`, they are useless. Cursor attributes explained: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS541

Answer (score 4):

I like this way:

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR my_cur
    IS
    SELECT 'a' AS a FROM DUAL WHERE 1=1;

    my_rec my_cur%rowtype;

BEGIN
    OPEN my_cur;
    LOOP

        FETCH my_cur INTO my_rec;

        IF my_cur%NOTFOUND
        THEN
            IF my_cur%ROWCOUNT=0
            THEN
                -- do stuff when cursor empty
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOTFOUND,RC=0' || '_' || my_cur%ROWCOUNT || '_' || my_rec.a);
            END IF;
            EXIT;
        ELSE
                -- do stuff when cursor not empty
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FOUND,RC>0' || '_' || my_cur%ROWCOUNT || '_' || my_rec.a);
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE MY_CUR;
END;
```

Output when cursor is 1=1 (not empty):

```
FOUND,RC>0_1_a
```

Output when cursor is 1=0 (empty):

```
NOTFOUND,RC=0_0_
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the same select query that comprises the cursor and select the count it returns into a variable.  You can then evaluate the variable to determine what to do next.  For example you have a cursor like this:

```
CURSOR c_example IS 
    SELECT field1
        ,field2
        ,field3
    FROM table1 a
    WHERE a.field1 LIKE '%something%';
```

Before you open the cursor to do any processing, select cursor result count into a variable.

```
SELECT count(*)
INTO v_exampleCount
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.field1 LIKE '%something%';
```

Now, again before you open cursor, do something like:

```
IF exampleCount>0 THEN

    FOR example IN c_example
    LOOP
        ....
    END LOOP;  --end example loop

    ....

END IF;  --end example if
```

Answer (score 0):

341/5000
One solution would be to work with reverse logic. It is e.g. not possible to ask:

```
IF my_record IS NULL THEN
   do something;
END IF;
```

or

```
IF my_record.my_attibute IS NULL THEN
   do something;
END IF;
```

Instead it is possible to ask:

```
IF my_record.my_attibute IS NOT NULL THEN
   go on processing;
ELSE
   do something;
END IF;
```