# how to check if SYS_REFCURSOR is empty

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a general SYS_REFCURSOR that I want to check if it is empty or not.

The code is like this:

```
declare
    v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
   OPEN v_cursor FOR <any select statement>.
   check if v_cursor is empty.
end;
```

Can someone tell me how to check if the weak cursor is empty, please?
I have to mention that the base SELECT statement can be anything from any table.
The column numbers or type it is known only at runtime.

Thank you,

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/10814111/1509264

Comment: In the posibile duplicate topic it is known the structure of returned data set while in my topic the structure of the data set could be anyhow.

Comment: If you don't know the structure, does that mean it is going to be consumed later by some calling process - so you aren't checking (and can't) while it is being fetched, as shown in the answers to the question MTO linked to? Fetching here would consume one row, anyway, if so - even if you knew the structure. Is the query a string - if so you could perhaps manipulate it and open&fetch/count once based on that, then open for real?

Comment: @AlexPoole, the data from the cursor will be sent as attachment in email, but only if it contains anything. If the cursor is empty, the email should not be sent.

Comment: OK, then doesn't the `is_found_rec` approach in the accepted answer let you do that? If you send the email after the loop then you can decide whether you should based on the flag. (Though you still need to know the structure, surely?)

Comment: I am not sure if I can do a FOR LOOP în a sys_refcursor. Else, I do not know how to use that flag

Comment: If the caller is a PL/SQL block, then the caller can use DBMS_SQL to describe the select list items and define outputs so that any select can be fetched. If the code is some other interface, then the caller in that interface would have to use similar capabilities of describing an arbitrary statement's columns and fetch into them. The usefulness of this activity is pretty low because if you received something and there are multiple rows to fetch, then the caller would have to provide some way to process a "row" along with the remaining rows to be fetched.

Comment: @JeffHolt, the caller is, indeed, PL/SQL. I will use the DBMS_SQL to parse the data from the cursor. It was a solution to use this to check if it is not empty, but I didn't know how to check only 1st row.

Comment: I really hate ref cursors. We were just fine for decades without them. The extended SQL tracing nightmare they cause is unforgivable.

Comment: @JeffHolt which decades were those? They existed in [Oracle 7](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/dcommon/oin/index.htm), mid-nineties.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson There's a big difference between a cursor variable and ref cursor. This question is regarding the latter.

Comment: @JeffHolt a [cursor variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/cursor-variable-declaration.html) is a ref cursor. This is unchanged since at least [Oracle 7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/PLS23/ch5.htm#using%20cur%20vars). The only change is the introduction of the predefined `sys_refcursor` type in 10.1 to save a line of code per package.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson You couldn't and can't pass a cursor variable back to a host program and then have that host program fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't see if a ref cursor contains data without fetching, and consuming at least one row from it.

If you really need to determine this at the point the cursor is opened, without knowing the structure at that point, you could execute a modified query that just counts the rows returned by your real query - possibly limited to a single row if that helps performance - either as a simple `execute immediate ... into ...` or with a separate open/fetch/close for consistency; something like:

```
declare
  v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_query VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_count PLS_INTEGER;
begin
  v_query := <any select statement>;

  -- see if the query finds any data
  OPEN v_cursor FOR 'select count(*) from (' || v_query || ')'; -- could limit rows
  FETCH v_cursor INTO v_count;
  CLOSE v_cursor;
  if v_count = 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('No data');
    return;
  end if;
  
  dbms_output.put_line('Found data, opening cursor for real');
  OPEN v_cursor FOR v_query;
  -- loop over results, return to caller, etc.
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=04b3b988f8563c8227db377b178ad42f)

Comment: I see your point. In conclusion, the option would be to create a new dynamic sql, based on the inițial one, that will surely return the count (a numerical type).

Answer (score 1):

Try to fetch a row and then use `v_cursor%NOTFOUND` to determine of the cursor is empty:

```sql
DECLARE
    v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_value  DUAL.DUMMY%TYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN v_cursor FOR SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 0;
   FETCH v_cursor INTO v_value;
   IF v_cursor%NOTFOUND THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cursor empty');
   ELSE
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cursor not empty');
   END IF;
END;
/
```

or

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR v_cursor IS
    SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 0;
  v_row v_cursor%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cursor;
  FETCH v_cursor INTO v_row;
  IF v_cursor%NOTFOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cursor empty');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cursor not empty');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Both output:

> ```
> Cursor empty
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=efca872513b43ea1351741d0499cb569)*

Comment: Not exactly what I expected because I don't know the structure of the SELECT statement. At a execution time it can be SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1 but asl well it can be SELECT x1, x2, x3 FROM t2.

Comment: @mikcutu You need to `OPEN` a cursor and try to `FETCH` a row from it to determine if the cursor is empty; to do that, you need to `FETCH` into something so you need be able to use either `%ROWTYPE` or know how many columns are in the cursor. If you do not know how many columns then you may be better using something like `DBMS_SQL` rather than a weak cursor.